# Magit always use current branch to create new branch

Tags: magit, git

I am currently on `master` branch and I have to create new branch called `test` starting from master.

If I run `b c` in magit buffer, magit will prompt for starting point

> Create branch starting at (default master):

How to prevent this and always use the current branch?

Comment: Are you sure you really need this? There is no such thing as default branch in git. Every branch is standard from technical point of view. This message in the minibuffer just tells you that if you press enter `master` branch will be used *by default*. This *default* may change depending on your previous choices. Always branching from `master` branch is not very good idea too. It may seem so if you work with simple pet projects, but once you work in a team, using something like [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), you will want to always explicitly choose

Comment: branch to branch off from.

Comment: @Mark  Yes. I meant to use current branch.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offered default *is* the current branch, therefore there already is a key binding for creating a new branch starting at the current branch. But that binding is <kbd>b c RET</kbd>, not <kbd>b c</kbd>.

Okay that was a slight simplification. If and only if there is a branch at point (e.g. in a log or the references buffer) then that branch is offered as the default instead.

Comment: in this context, can i bind `c RET` to `c` itself?

Comment: No, but you can copy the definition of `magit-branch`, look at what happens inside `magit-branch-read-args` and do something similar inside the `interactive` of the copy. Then you have to bind that new command in the popup as described [here](http://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup/Customizing-existing-popups.html). I.e. my claim that there is a key binding `b c RET` is not technically correct.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example implementation along the lines you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a Magit version newer than 2.8 (the relevant commit was on 2016-10-10), you can customize the user option `magit-no-confirm-default`.

If you add `magit-branch-and-checkout` to that list, then when you use <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> you will only need to enter the new branch name, and Magit will use the default start point without prompting you.

*n.b. That default start point is contextual! The prompt for the new branch will indicate what the start point will be.*

e.g. If you are viewing a Magit Log or Magit Refs buffer, the start point would reflect the ref at point, rather than the branch you currently have checked out.

Comment: I have magit 3.3 and the option `magit-no-confirm-default` is not available.

Comment: Search the release notes and you'll find that in v2.12: "The option `magit-no-confirm-default` has been demoted to a variable and will be removed in v2.13.0.  Please migrate your customizations to the new option `magit-dwim-selection`."

Comment: But the `magit-dwim-selection` customization does not offer settings for branch creation. Also, nearly everything is already set to "use default without confirmation".

Comment: You're not limited to the commands which are included in that option by default.  Simply add the command `magit-branch-and-checkout` and "use default without confirmation" for the prompt regexp `^Create and checkout branch starting at`.

Comment: Sadly that does not work,magit still asks for the starting branch.

Comment: I can't help, then -- that's what I've tested locally, and it works for me; the only thing I'm prompted for is the name of the new branch.

Comment: Could you add the corresponding lisp expression?

Comment: I tested using the customize UI.

Comment: Then maybe you could edit a screenshot into your answer, because I did it as you described it and it does not work for me.

Comment: I have no insight into whatever difference is preventing my suggestion from working for you, so I recommend you instead write yourself a custom command which does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tarsius mentions, you can define your own command to do this.

```el
(defun wh/magit-branch-from-current-and-checkout (branch)
  "Create and checkout BRANCH from the current branch."
  (interactive (list (magit-read-string-ns "Branch name")))
  (let ((start-point (magit-get-current-branch)))
    (if (string-match-p "^stash@{[0-9]+}$" start-point)
        (magit-run-git "stash" "branch" branch start-point)
      (magit-call-git "checkout" "-b" branch start-point)
      (--when-let (and (magit-get-upstream-branch branch)
                       (magit-get-indirect-upstream-branch start-point))
        (magit-call-git "branch" (concat "--set-upstream-to=" it) branch))
      (magit-refresh))))
```

You can add this to the existing branch popup. In this case, I've chosen <kbd>b f</kbd> as the keybinding (as it's currently unused).

```el
(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-branch-popup
  ?f "new branch From current" #'wh/magit-branch-from-current-and-checkout)
```

If you don't have unpushed commits on your current branch, you can also use <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> (bound to `magit-branch-spinoff`) to create a new branch without prompting for the base branch.